# What is wrong with this Oracle stored proc call?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have a stored proc with the signature:

```
PROCEDURE contract_boq_import(i_project_id IN RAW, i_master_list_version IN NUMBER,
                             i_force_update_if_exists IN BOOLEAN, i_user_id IN NUMBER)
```

And when I try and call it, in SQL Developer as follows:

```
exec PA_PRJ_IMP.contract_boq_import('B3F4C5933008B348B753F95AA99B3678', 3, 1, 3920)
```

I get the following error:

```
wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CONTRACT_BOQ_IMPORT'
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: `1` isn't a boolean value...? Your first value also isn't `RAW`.

Comment: I didn't know how else to express a RAW value. In PL-SQL, how do I use a boolean literal except 1 or 0?

Comment: [`BOOLEAN`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-data-types.html#GUID-02AEA63C-9A27-43F4-80B7-4781343445D0) values are true or false (or null, if you count that as a value), not 1 and 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `'B3F4C5933008B348B753F95AA99B3678'` is a `varchar` value, not a `RAW` value.

You need to convert it to RAW in the call. Additionally, you need to pass a boolean value for the third parameter - `1` is a number.

```
exec PA_PRJ_IMP.contract_boq_import(hextoraw('B3F4C5933008B348B753F95AA99B3678'), 3, true, 3920);
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is because you're passing the number `1` when it's expecting a [`BOOLEAN`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-data-types.html#GUID-02AEA63C-9A27-43F4-80B7-4781343445D0) value; and there is no implicit conversion between those data types:

```
exec PA_PRJ_IMP.contract_boq_import('B3F4C5933008B348B753F95AA99B3678', 3, 1, 3920);

PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CONTRACT_BOQ_IMPORT'
```

Changing that to TRUE (or FALSE) works:

```
exec PA_PRJ_IMP.contract_boq_import('B3F4C5933008B348B753F95AA99B3678', 3, TRUE, 3920);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

But you probably want to explicitly convert the first argument to `RAW` as well; it will be implicitly converted but it's better to be explicit:

```
exec PA_PRJ_IMP.contract_boq_import(hextoraw('B3F4C5933008B348B753F95AA99B3678'), 3, TRUE, 3920);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Quick [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=06d0ba96c9ac3a808c6e18bc2f1e7a7f), including showing that implicit conversion happened (in second call).